# How can I assign pytorch tensor a matrix from numpy?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Create WxW tensor:

```
x = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(W,W).zero_(), requires_grad=True)
```

Do some calculations:

```
x_copy = x0=np.copy(x.data.numpy())
x_upd = handleArray(x_copy)
```

How can I assign x data from x_upd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to do:

```
x.data.from_numpy(x_upd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `tensor.from_numpy()`

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/tensor_tutorial.html